# How to change TINYINT value NULL to DEFAULT '0'

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to edit a column in a MySQL table. Right now, it is tinyint with value NULL. I want to change the value to '0'. I tried using this expression:

`ALTER TABLE hosts MODIFY COLUMN hide TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;`
and this
`ALTER TABLE hosts MODIFY COLUMN hide TINYINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL;`
and more variations. But this didn't work for me..

I get this error

```
EXECUTE FAIL:

ALTER TABLE hosts MODIFY COLUMN hide TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL

Message :

  Invalid use of NULL value
```

What's the problem and what is the correct statement?

Comment: First fix data second alter table..modify column.

Comment: @P.Salmon ? What do you mean "fix data"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot alter the table to „not null“ as long as you have data in it with null value.

First set all you data to 0

```
Update hosts set hide = 0 where hide is null
```